# Change featured image urls in database

Tags: post-thumbnails, mysql

Im storing my images on another server and Ive managed to change the urls in the database but I cant seem to change the featured image urls?

I will not be adding any more images so I just want to change the url for all images.

This is the sql I used for normal images

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'src="http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'src="http://newsiteurl.com');
```

and

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET  guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://newsiteurl.com') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

All the other images are fine except the featured images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The featured image is stored in the `*_postmeta` table under the `_thumbnail_id` key. In fact, chances are that you've got a lot of image/media urls in that table, which you haven't changed. The problem is that a number of things are stored in serialized arrays and changing them with SQL as above will (probably) break those arrays. I would suggest using something like [Velvet Blues Update Urls](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/).

It looks like you have changed all of your URLs and not just the image/media URLs. Is that what you intended?

[Also, you should never change the guid.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note)

NOTE and EDIT: I just noticed an exception for attachment media in the WordPress Codex. I don't remember ever seeing that and I am not sure what that is about and I am not sure what to make of that at the moment.

Comment: +1 for the guid comment, it is an identifier, not an output.

Comment: Yes I meant to change the GUID it included `WHERE post_type = 'attachment'`. Thanks, I get the whole feed issue but I still dont really know why I'd want old urls on my site after a domain change or at least a change from local development to live site (I know I should use version control but that confuses the hell out of me).

Comment: They aren't URLs, not really. They look like URLs but they aren't. Any globally unique string would work. URLs are co-opted because it is a fairly reliable way to create unique strings. It would be less confusing if it were hashed, or something similar, as hinted at in the Codex by the phrase "some representation of the url".